# Probability density of sum of two beta random variables

Tags: self-study, random-variable, density-function, joint-distribution, beta-distribution

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are independent and have beta distributions. $X$ has probability density function $g(x)=6x(1-x)$ for $ 0\leq x \leq 1$ and $Y$ has the probability density function $h(y)=12y^2(1-y)$ for $0\leq y \leq 1$. I want to find $P(X+Y\leq 1)$.

#### Answer

I have calculated $f(x,y)=72x^2(1-x)y^2(1-y);0 \leq y \leq 1$. How do I compute $p(X+Y\leq 1)$? Expert's guidance is needed. The answer given to me is $\frac{13}{35}$, but how is it computed?

Comment: This question is squarely about statistics and conforms to the self-study guidelines. I vote to keep it open.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then answer is easy and comes from the fact that $p(a,b)=p(a)p(b|a)$ then

$$
P(X+Y\leq 1) = \int_x P(X=x)P(Y\leq 1-x)
$$
if you replace $P(X)$ and $P(Y)$ by $g(x)$ and $h(y)$ then you get the result.
$$
P(X+Y\leq 1) = \int_0^1 g(x)\int_0^{1-x}h(y)dydx
$$
The final answer would be $72*(1/90-1/168)$.

Comment: Well, strictly speaking $P(X=x) = 0$...

Comment: I see but the underlying assumption is small intervals for continues variables. (we usually do not mention that)

Answer (score 5):

Not an expert but here are some hints:

1) You do not actually need to derive the pdf of the $X+Y$ but merely perform the integration over the set $\left\{ \left(x,y\right): x+y \leq 1 , \  0 < x,y < 1 \right\}$, which you can plot to get the idea.

2) The area of integration turns out to be quite convenient as you can use the result

$$\int_{0}^1 x^{a-1} \left(1-x\right)^{b-1} \mathrm{dx} = \frac{\Gamma(a) \Gamma(b) }{ \Gamma (a + b) }$$

where $\Gamma(x)$ is the gamma function with the property that $\Gamma(x) = (x-  1)!$. You should be able to get to the result now.

Comment: How can I use the result in 2) given in your answer? Please elaborate on it.